# Captured output from a cmd.exe command is missing a final newline

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, command-line, command

I'm trying to call a built-in `cmd` command like `echo` in PowerShell using `Invoke-Expression` and convert it to a byte array, but the newlines are missing from the command output.

Example:

```
([Text.Encoding]::ASCII).GetBytes((iex "cmd /c echo."))
```

It returns nothing instead of a newline sequence (CRLF).

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. Why are you trying to get a newline byte sequence by running `echo` via `Invoke-Expression` instead of, say, `[Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes([Environment]::NewLine)` or simply `[byte[]](13,10)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

```
PS> ([text.encoding]::ASCII).GetBytes(((cmd /c echo.) -join "`r`n") + "`r`n")
13
10
```

<sup>As an aside: [`iex` (`Invoke-Expression`) should be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/)
.</sup>

Read on for background information and caveats.

---

When **PowerShell captures stdout output from an external program** such as `cmd.exe`, it returns an ***array* of output *lines***, with the trailing newline sequence *trimmed* from each.

As an aside: It is the **character encoding** reported by `[console]::OutputEncoding` that determines how PowerShell interprets the output, which in *Windows PowerShell* defaults to the legacy system locale's OEM code page, and, as of this writing, also - still -in PowerShell Core *on Windows*, though that [will hopefully change soon](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7233), given that PowerShell Core otherwise uses (BOM-less) UTF-8 as the default encoding.

In your case, `cmd /c echo.` emitted a single Windows newline sequence, CRLF, which, in PowerShell terms, is `` "`r`n" `` (you can also use `[Environment]::NewLine` to obtain a platform-appropriate newline string).

PowerShell interprets that as a single empty line, and, due to not including the trailing newline in the array elements and PowerShell unwrapping a single-element array, you end up with `''`, i.e., the *empty string* - this is why the `([text.encoding]::ASCII).GetBytes()` call produced no output.

You can *reassemble* the output-lines array that PowerShell created into a single, multi-line output string by:

- joining the array elements with newlines (`` -join "`r`n" ``)
- appending a final trailing newline  (`` + "`r`n" ``)

as shown above.

**Caveats**: This **"reassembly" makes two assumptions** that may not always be true:

- That the external program really emitted Windows CRLF sequences and not UNIX LF-only characters.

  - In practice, however, that difference rarely matters in PowerShell, because it accepts both newline forms *interchangeably*.
- That the external program really emitted a *trailing* newline - which is typically, but not necessarily true.

If these assumptions are problematic, **redirecting the output to a file** and **reading *that*** - as in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54497037/45375) - is the right solution.

**Caveat**: `>` in Windows PowerShell creates UTF-16LE files by default (and also invariably appends a newline), so you won't get *ASCII* bytes; therefore, use `cmd`'s *own* redirection to produce the file (which will use the legacy OEM encoding indicated by `chcp`, which is typically a *superset* of ASCII):

```
  # Note that the `>` is *inside the quoted string* to ensure that it is
  # cmd.exe that interprets it.
  # (...) around `echo.` ensures that the space before `>` doesn't become
  # part of the output.
  PS> cmd /c '(echo.) >out.txt'; [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$PWD\out.txt")
  13
  10
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Not perfect but i will write output to file, read it with `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("path_to_the_file")`
and save to variable